# What are all the invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z_m}$ for $m = 30$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I know all of the invertible elements? Is it just all of the numbers that are relatively prime to 30?

Comment: These posts are also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117260/how-to-determine-all-the-invertible-elements and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82313/an-invertible-element-i-in-mathbb-z-n-must-be-coprime-to-n (And you can probably find more similar questions.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. To prove this, note that the smallest number that can be written as a linear combination of $k$ and $30$ is the greatest common divisor of $k$ and $30$; if $k \in \mathbb{Z}_m$ is invertible, one can write

$$k s \equiv 1 \pmod{30} \iff ks + 30 r = 1$$

for appropriate $s, r$.

Comment: So it doesn't matter whether $m$ is prime or not?

Comment: @user3064097 In general, no. But if $m$ is prime, it's *really* easy to see what it's relatively prime to.

Comment: So if you have a composite composed of unique primes a*b*c, what is the size of invertible elements, (a-1)(b-1)(c-1)?

Comment: @user3064097 Have a look at the [totient function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since $\, \exists\, x\!:\, ax\equiv 1\pmod{30}\iff \exists\, x,y\!: ax+30y = 1\iff \gcd(a,30)=1\,$ by [Bezout.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)